# WhatsApp online status for strangers

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

If I don't have John in my phone contacts (and thus I don't have him in my WhatsApp contacts), and then I open WhatsApp main window, will John see me online? I know my contacts will, but will John?

By "see me online" I mean: if he opens the conversation view with me, will he see the "online" label under my name?

Note: Suppose John has my phone number in his contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Being **online** can't be hidden as long as the person is not blocked. But you can choose who can see your *last seen at* information at

Whatsapp -> Top right "three dot" menu -> Settings -> Account -> Privacy -> Last seen

Answer (score 1):

> By "see me online" I mean: if he opens the conversation view with me,
>   will he see the "online" label under my name?

Yes - he will be able to see that you are Online.

As per the [official FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/23225461/?category=5245250) of WhatsApp,

> There is no way to hide when you are online or typing.